# Kotlin - spread operator in SpringApplicationBuilder

Tags: spring, sonarqube, kotlin

[image: SonarQube error]

Is there any alternative to using a spread operator in such case? Or should I ignore the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is called once when creating the application, I would ignore this warning.

Essentially, that call is going to get compiled down to something like this (in Java):

```
Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length));
```

If you were to do this in a loop, or very frequently under load the warning would make sense. But for app-startup and only once at that, I'd just ignore it.

Comment: Agree: Adding an @Suppress on the method so Sonarqube doesn't keep flagging it, and you can add a comment so others don't wonder why it's suppressed.